# What's the order of operations when dealing with function composition?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$, $g(x)=x^2$.

Which of the two equalities is true?

1)$f^2(x^2)=f^2(g(x))=(f^2\circ g)(x)$;

2)$f^2(x^2)=f(x^2)\cdot f(x^2)=f(g(x))\cdot f(g(x))=(f\circ g)(x)\cdot (f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ g)^2(x).$

Note: here $f^2$ is defined as the [2-fold product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers) of $f$ and not composition.

Comment: Your link confuses me. Your link is named "2-fold product" and links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers , which is not product. You named your link product, but you link to function composition. The linked section states that " f: X→Y may **compose** with itself; this is sometimes denoted as f²".

Answer (score 1):

The first equality is true, because $f^2(x)$ is usually defined to be $(f \circ f)(x) = f\big(f(x)\big)$, and $(f \circ g)(x)$ is defined as $f\big(g(x)\big)$. Because of these definitions, the second equality does not hold. However, if the notation $f^2$ or $\circ$ is differently defined, any one or possibly both equalities may be true.

Comment: What if I define $f^2$ to be the [2-fold product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers) of $f$?

Comment: @Alexandru-OctavianBadea I'm sorry if I'm not understanding something, but I believe I *have* defined $f^2$ as a 2-fold product in my answer according to your link.

Comment: In the answer, you defined $f^2$ to be the composition of $f$ with itself, but based on Wikipedia, the 2-fold product of a function is simply the function raised to the 2nd power. [(Note: If f takes its values in a ring (in particular for real or complex-valued f ), there is a risk of confusion, as f n could also stand for the n-fold product of f, e.g. $f^2(x) = f(x) · f(x)$.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers)